# Devise URL Helpers are not being generated on reset password procedure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to implement reset password feature from Devise on my Rails App. It works fine but after sending email instructions it redirects to a wrong URL (`api/sessions/new` insteadof `users/sign_in`). Looking on devise code I found that it calls this method to get the url:

```
# The path used after sending reset password instructions
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  new_session_path(resource_name) if is_navigational_format?
end
```

The resource_name is "user" and the `new_session_path("user")` is returning the matching route `new_session_path` on `routes.rb` file. The expected response should be `new_user_session_path`.

There is an URL Helper on Devise that should translate `new_session_path(:user)` to `new_user_session_path` but it is not working: http://www.rubydoc.org/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/UrlHelpers#generate_helpers%21-class_method

Does anyone know why ? Should I call manually the generate_helpers! method ?

My Rails version is 3.2.14 and Devise 3.2.2.

Best regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a `SessionsController` which was overriding the Devise SessionsController and the routes paths. After rename my SessionsController It worked fine.